# Samba groups not working

Tags: linux, centos, samba, groups

I am trying to get samba working with groups. I am using CentOS.

```
#sswords = yes
lanman auth = no
null passwords = no
hosts allow = 129.130.155.
netbios name = a server
server string = base PHP server
[team$]
 path= /var/www
 writable = yes
 valid users = @team
 force group = @team
```

I have created a few users in linux, and added them to a group called team using

groupadd -a -g username.

**I the attempted to login and got a NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_GROUP**.
If I comment out the two last lines in the config it works, but I wish to have group ownership and prefer just to be able to add users to a group in Linux and for it to work with the samba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
force group = team
```

You are trying to force the group with the content of the group itself (the members of the group) instead forcing the group name.